# Python Errno 10054 while working with Selenium and BeautifuSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download all the PDF files which can be downloaded without login or subscription on [this web page](https://www.osapublishing.org/search.cfm?q=comsol&meta=1&cj=1&cc=1), but I got this error.

```
[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

How can I solve this error?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 as ul

def download_pdf(file_name, download_url):
    response = ul.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open(file_name + ".pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    print("Completed")

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\HarutakaKawamura\Desktop\bs\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://www.osapublishing.org/search.cfm?q=comsol&meta=1&cj=1&cc=1')

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'PDF')]")
titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[contains(@class, 'sri-title')]")

for i in range(len(links)):

    href = links[i].get_attribute("href")
    bs = BeautifulSoup(ul.urlopen(href), 'lxml')

    if len(str(bs)) < 1000:

        download_url = bs.findAll("frame")[1]['src']
        file_name = titles[i].find_element_by_tag_name("a").text
        download_pdf(file_name, download_url)
```

Comment: Did you manage to download some PDF or you have the error before any download?

Comment: It's random. Sometimes I get the error after some PDF are downloaded, and sometimes before any download.

Comment: Ok so try to catch the error and send your request again

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import socket
import errno

def download_pdf(file_name, download_url):
    error_counter = 0
    while error_counter <= 5:
        try:
            response = ul.urlopen(download_url)
            file = open(file_name + ".pdf", 'wb')
            file.write(response.read())
            file.close()
            print("Completed")
            break
        except socket.error as error:
            if error.errno == errno.ECONNRESET:
                error_counter += 1
            else:
                raise
```